# position subtitles in the middle of the video height using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles

Assume my video resolution is 848x480. I add subtitles on the video and I want it to be positioned on the middle of the video. How to do it? (Please write a solution that can position the subtitle at video.height/3,  video.height/4 also and so on..

ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -filter_complex [0:v]subtitles='subtitles.srt:force_style='FontName=opensans_extrabold',fontsize=30' -c:a copy -preset superfast -y output.mp4

This command positions the subtitles at the bottom of the video. I tried using marginV=240 (half of the height) and it positions the subtitles on the top of the video

Edit: I can use Alignment=10 but I want to control the height by pixels and not always in the middle